# Image from URI in Windows Forms app

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, image, uri

I work in C#, .Net 4.0, but I have a Windows Forms application.
I want to create `Image` object from `Uri`. Every link I found was about WPF applications, but I work in Windows Forms.

```
Image x = new Image();
//this doesn't work for me
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code simply creates a new `Image` object with default properties. I don't see where you try to use a `Uri` at all.

Use [`WebClient.OpenRead`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.openread.aspx) to get a stream from the `Uri` and [`Image.FromStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x.aspx) to get an image from it.

```
var wc = new WebClient();
Image x = Image.FromStream(wc.OpenRead(uri));
```

Comment: I got a WebException:
Uri myUri = slidePart.ImageParts.ElementAt(0).Uri;
var wc = new WebClient();
Image pic1 = Image.FromStream(wc.OpenRead(myUri));

Comment: @user966638 - Are you sure you have a valid `Uri` and that you don't need to specify any credentials to get to it? Can you edit your question and post the complete exception details?

Comment: Yes, it's value is "/ppt/media/image2.png"

Comment: @user966638 - You expect `WebClient` to "know" this is a local url? I suggest you give it the full Uri, including protocol and domain.